# Solution for Missing integer problem of codility in php 100% score

Tags: php, algorithm, integer

**Problem** Find the smallest positive integer that does not occur in a given sequence.

So what is the best implementation in PHP for this problem of codility!

Solution below results 66%, causing performance issue.

```
function solution($A)
{
    sort($A);
    $end = count($A);
    $flag = false;
    for ($k = 0; $flag == false; $k++, $flag = false) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $end; $i++) {
            if ($k + 1 == $A[$i]) {
                $flag = $A[$i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if($flag == false){
            return $k +1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution using an associative array as a set:

```
function solution($A) {
    $set = array_flip($A);
    for ($n = 1; ; ++$n) {
        if (!isset($set[$n])) {
            return $n;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Best solution for the codility problem implemented in PHP, scoring 100%

```
function solution($A)
{
    sort($A);
    $end = count($A);
    $flag = false;
    for ($k = 1, $i = 0; $i < $end; $i++) {
      if ($A[$i] == $k) {
        $k++;
        continue;
      } elseif ($A[$i] < $k)
        continue;
      else return $k;
      }
      return $k;
    }
```

Comment: How have you found the answer? Can you recommend any book or something so that I can learn?
I also solved it but it was not 100%.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't used any book, rather just developed the logic myself.

Answer (score 0):

I got 88%.

```
>     function solution($A) {
>         // Implement your solution here
>         $max = max($A);
>         if($max <=0){
>             return 1;
>         }
>         $A = array_unique($A);
>         sort($A);
>         
>         $flag = true;
>         if(count($A) == 1){
>             if($A[0] != 1){
>                 return 1;
>             }else{
>                 return 2;
>             }
>         }
>         for($i=0; $i<count($A)-1; $i++){
>             if(($A[$i]>0) && $flag){
>                 $flag = false;
>                 if($A[$i] !=1){
>                     return 1;
>                 }
>             }
>             if($A[$i]>0){
>                 if($A[$i]+1 != $A[$i+1]){
>                     return $A[$i]+1;
>                 }            
>             }
>     
>         }
>         return $A[count($A)-1]+1;
>     }
```